# Async JSON Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

I need to do a RestRequest and get some JSON, I am not sure if my method is really async since there is still a little freeze in my UI when I use this method.

```
 public async Task<List<MyObject>> Load() 
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Myobject>>();
                var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://exampleapi.com");
                client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(
           [...]);
                var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("examp.json", Method.GET);
                client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        List_ = new List<MyObject>();
                        List_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(response.Content);
                        tcs.SetResult(List_);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }
                });
                return await tcs.Task;        
            }
```

Specially for this line of code :

```
List_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(response.Content);
```

is it really async ? because it seems to block the the UI . Can you tell me how can I make this function properly async ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems the delegate passed as an argument to `ExecuteAsync` is being executed on the UI thread. If that is the case, simply use `Task.Run` to run the delegate on the threadpool instead.

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, async (response) =>
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var list = await Task.Run( () => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(response.Content));
            tcs.SetResult(list);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    });
```

Is `List_` a field? It seems to me like it should be a local variable. Also, there's no need to initialize it with an empty list before deserializing the json.

Comment: Thank you I removed the initialization of my List as well, generally how can I know if an operation is executed on my UI Thread ?

Comment: @user2505650 To be honest, I don't know much about the Windows Phone API, but here's a simple test: Add `Thread.Sleep(5000)` and run the code - if it blocks the UI, then it's being run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is synchronous. You can tell by the fact that it returns you the result of its computation immediately. There is no way it could do something "in the background" and only later hand you the result.

Move CPU bound work to a thread-pool thread using `Task.Run`. You can move the whole REST request there if that is more convenient to you.

Note, that your message box call should run on the UI thread. Better not create a message box on a thread-pool thread like you are doing at the moment. That will result in two UI threads. The message box will not be modal.

Comment: Thank you, i will change my MessageBox, but how can I tel if an operation is executed on the UI thread or not?

Comment: That is usually documented. I'm sure RestSharp documents on what thread the callback will be invoked.