# Parallel.Foreach() vs. await/async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I know there are a few other questions that touch on this topic but I'm trying to figure out if I'm on the right track and if I'm missing something.

Basically, I have a loop that calls an `async` method that goes and makes an HTTP call and parses a JSON reply.  I am trying to find the best way to call that method.  Currently I do it this way:

The method signature: `async Task<List<Item>> GetItemData(string item);`

```
foreach(var item in itemList)
{
    var test = await GetItemData(item);
}
```

It works fine, but is slow (`itemList` might contain 300-500 items and takes about 150000 ms).  I thought I might try to add a `Parallel.Foreach` and did it this way:

```
Parallel.ForEach(itemList, (item) =>
{
    var test = GetItemData(item).Result;
});
```

If I added an `async` keyword to the lambda, and omitted the `.Result`, it caused issues.  So, my question is, is there any reason why I might not want to do it the second way?  Calling a `.Result` seems counter intuitive to try and do something in an `async` fashion but the second method works almost twice as fast.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you added `async` to the lambda, did you add await as well?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane That still won't work.  `Parallel.Foreach` is not designed for asynchronous work.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39796934/5311735

Comment: Based on your question the reason why you are probably not getting the "asynchronous-feel" is due to the fact that JSON deserialization/serialization will block your thread.

Not to drive you away from doing `Parallel` work, I would start with doing something as plain as putting your `Json.DeserializeObject<T>()` into it's own thread. `await Task.Run(() => Json...);` an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014988/3645638

Comment: To get all the items in parallel dont await the task directly, do:
`foreach(var task in itemList.Select(x => GetItemData(x)).ToList())
{
    var test = await task;
}` Let me know if you got any performance improvement.

Comment: @Evk thanks for pointing me in the direction of that question; I hadn't found that when I was looking before.  I'll take a look at some of the suggestions there and see what I can come up with.