# JsonReader only reads JValue of type string

Tags: c#, json, websocket, stream, json.net

In my scenario two servers talk via a secured WebSocket connection. Sent messages are well defined json objects. Since I'm dealing with WebSockets I use streams to deserialize the received json into objects.

However, in my custom converter the received json always gets deserialized into a JValue of type string. I spent the better part of the day trying to fix this and in the end had to convert the JValue to a string just to parse it back into a JObject, and -- as far as I can tell -- totally negating the advantage of a stream based approach.

Is this the intended behaviour? If not, how can I fix this?

This is the code in question. The custom serializes is registered in the `SerializerSettings` object.

```
public Task ReceiveAsync(WebSocket socket, WebSocketReceiveResult result, byte[] buffer)
{
    SocketMessage message;
    try
    {
        var ser = JsonSerializer.Create(this.SerializerSettings);
        using (var sReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(buffer)))
        {
            using (var jReader = new JsonTextReader(sReader))
            {
                message = ser.Deserialize<SocketMessage>(jReader);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException jex)
    {
        this.Logger.LogError(1, jex, "Received json was not in the correct format.");
        return Task.FromException(jex);
    }
    //... Remainder removed for brevity
}


public class SocketMessage
{
    public SocketMessage()
    {
        this.Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>(5);
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }

    public JToken Content { get; set; }
}


public sealed class SocketMessageJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SocketMessage);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jString = (string)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        var jVal = JObject.Parse(jString);

        var headers = jVal.Children<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => p.Name.Equals("headers", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Values()
            .Children()
            .Select(c => c as JProperty)
            .Where(p => p != null)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (string)p.Value);

        return new SocketMessage
        {
            Headers = headers,
            Content = jVal["content"],
        };
    }
}
```

Here is a sample Json that was received (taken with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');`)
The `Content` property is an arbitrary property that is, based on certain header fields, going to be deserialized elsewhere in the code. Therefore I only store it as `JObject` in the `SocketMessage`.

> @"{""headers"":{""action"":""opened""},""content"":""address"":""localhost"",""map_servers"":[]}}"

Comment: The issue is with the async method.  You cannot deserialize until you receive the entire response.  Using async in your code you are trying to deserialize before getting entire response which is giving the error.

Comment: My bad, I totally forgot a sample of the JSON. See edited Question.

Comment: @jdweng That's why I used streams in the first place. JSON.NET supports async (de-)serialization via streams. My first attempt was to get the whole string via `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)`, which I can directly deserialize via `JToken.Parse`, but later I switched to streams to make use of the new async support in JSON.NET

Comment: What about using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014830/async-json-deserialization

Comment: Your link points to a solution, that only wraps a synchronous method in a `Task.Run()`. This was the solution JSON.NET took until v10 to expose async workflow. However, this is a very bad solution and shouldn't be done (see this issue on the JSON.NET GitHub page: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/66). Therefore, proper async method should use streams, as shown on the official blog: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2017/03/21/json-net-10-0-release-1-async-performance-documentation-and-more