# Cannot deserialize the current json object into ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, json.net

(Full error message at the bottom of the post)

I am aware that this has already been discussed in several other posts, however, the fixes provided in those posts seems to not work for me.

I am providing all my code below. The deserialization is in the method `parseSpellData()`.

sample JSON:

```
{
"_id": "58c9eb75c9e7ce9f7214efaa",
"index": 1,
"name": "Acid Arrow",
"desc": [
    "A shimmering green arrow streaks toward a target within range and bursts in a spray of acid. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 4d4 acid damage immediately and 2d4 acid damage at the end of its next turn. On a miss, the arrow splashes the target with acid for half as much of the initial damage and no damage at the end of its next turn."
],
"higher_level": [
    "When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the damage (both initial and later) increases by 1d4 for each slot level above 2nd."
],
"page": "phb 259",
"range": "90 feet",
"components": [
    "V",
    "S",
    "M"
],
"material": "Powdered rhubarb leaf and an adder’s stomach.",
"ritual": "no",
"duration": "Instantaneous",
"concentration": "no",
"casting_time": "1 action",
"level": 2,
"school": {
    "url": "http://dnd5eapi.co/api/magic-schools/5",
    "name": "Evocation"
},
"classes": [
    {
        "name": "Wizard",
        "url": "http://dnd5eapi.co/api/classes/12"
    }
],
"subclasses": [
    {
        "url": "http://dnd5eapi.co/api/subclasses/2",
        "name": "Lore"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://dnd5eapi.co/api/subclasses/4",
        "name": "Land"
    }
],
"url": "http://dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/1"
}
```

Code:

```
class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Spell> availableSpells { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Spell>();


    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        availableSpells = parseSpellData(getSpells());
    }


    public string getSpells()
    {
        string spells = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://dnd5eapi.co/api/Spells") as HttpWebRequest;

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    spells = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(spells);
        return spells;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Spell> parseSpellData(string listOfSpells)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Spell> parsedSpellData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Spell>>(listOfSpells); 

        return parsedSpellData as ObservableCollection<Spell>;
    }        
}

public class School
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Spell
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> desc { get; set; }
    public List<string> higher_level { get; set; }
    public string page { get; set; }
    public string range { get; set; }
    public List<string> components { get; set; }
    public string material { get; set; }
    public string ritual { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string concentration { get; set; }
    public string casting_time { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public School school { get; set; }
    public List<Class> classes { get; set; }
    public List<Subclass> subclasses { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

PM Vizualization Error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.{"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection´1[NInterpret.interpretedObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (eg. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type likan an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

Comment: The JSON you posted is not an array, which is what the observable collection needs. I'm not sure what the question is? You should deserialize it as a single item and add it to the collection if you really want to use an observable collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON is not an array, it's an object containing an array-valued property.  You can see this more clearly if you format the JSON returned by http://dnd5eapi.co/api/Spells using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/:

```
{
   "count":305,
   "results":[
      {
         "name":"Acid Arrow",
         "url":"http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Acid Splash",
         "url":"http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/2"
      }
      // Additional entries omitted
   ]
}
```

Thus you need to deserialize to a model that contains a `"results"` collection, rather than to the collection itself.  One easy way to do this is to use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) to specify the wrapper root object:

```
public ObservableCollection<Spell> parseSpellData(string listOfSpells)
{
    var parsedSpellData = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(listOfSpells, new { results = (ObservableCollection<Spell>)null });

    return parsedSpellData.results;
}
```

Working [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xrDUFU).

Of course you could specify an explicit type for the root as well -- in fact your `MainPageViewModel` could be used for this purpose if you add [`[JsonProperty("results")]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor_1.htm) to `availableSpells`:

```
class MainPageViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public ObservableCollection<Spell> availableSpells { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Spell>();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(getSpells(), this);
    }
```

Sample working [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDl7K6).

Actually, your data model seems to have many properties not present in the JSON, where the returned objects in the returned `"results"` array contain only `"name"` and `"url"` properties.  Are you sure you are using the correct data model for this particular API?

**Update**

It looks like the JSON posted in your question is returned by the specific spell API URLs listed in the returned results, e.g. http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/1, which furthermore corresponds to your `Spell` type.  If you're looking to fetch all that spell data at once, you could introduce the following types

```
public class NameAndUri
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class NameAndUri<T> : NameAndUri
{
    public T Deserialize()
    {
        return JsonExtensions.DeserializeFromUri<T>(url);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeAnonymousTypeFromUri<T>(string uri, T anonymousTypeObject)
    {
        return DeserializeFromUri<T>(uri);
    }

    public static T DeserializeFromUri<T>(string uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

And modify `MainPageViewModel` as follows:

```
class MainPageViewModel
{
    public const string spellUri = "http://dnd5eapi.co/api/Spells";

    public ObservableCollection<Spell> availableSpells { get; set; } // = new ObservableCollection<Spell>();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        availableSpells = parseSpellData(spellUri);
    }

    static ObservableCollection<Spell> parseSpellData(string spellUri)
    {
        var parsedSpellData = JsonExtensions.DeserializeAnonymousTypeFromUri(spellUri, new { results = (List<NameAndUri<Spell>>)null });            
        var query = parsedSpellData.results.Select(s => s.Deserialize());
        return new ObservableCollection<Spell>(query);
    }   
}
```

Notes:

- As recommended in [Newtonsoft: Performance Tips](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage) I am deserializing directly from the response streams rather than loading into an intermediate `string`.
- You might want to replace the `School`, `Class` and `Subclass` types with `NameAndUri<T>` for some appropriate `T`.
- If the performance of loading all the spells at once is not good enough, consider moving to an [async solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25014830/3744182).

Sample [fiddle #3](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FoodJE) which times out on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ but works locally.

Comment: @ThorGiversen - updated with solution that downloads all spells at once.