# Read a json file async vs 2017 .net core

Tags: c#, async-await, json.net

I have a bunch of json files that I need to read.
Is it possible to convert this code to be fully async?
Is there a better way to do this?

```
public static T LoadJsonFile<T>(this Assembly assembly, string fullFilename) where T : new()
    {
        T result;

        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fullFilename);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

THis is not a duplicate because I am asking how to read a json file not using HTTPCLIENT

any samples?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async JSON Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014830/async-json-deserialization)

Comment: @tura08 the question you point out is about HttpClient .There is no Httpclient involved in mine

Comment: Accessing via HTTP or Stream is irrelevant. As they say in the question, they are interested in making this line async: `List_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(response.Content);`. As you can see, the answer is to wrap this in a `Task.Run` and await it. You can also read your stream async with `ReadToEndAsync()`.

Comment: okish.. well as you know Task.Run will create a thread on the threadpool and not async.. .So are you saying that I could change to ReadToEndAsync but then is blocked by Task.Run which will run syncronously.Am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "but then is blocked by Task.Run"? Using `ReadToEndAsync` would be an *alternative* to using `Task.Run`. But ultimately, you should think about what you're hoping to achieve from the asynchrony anyway. Using `Task.Run` with synchronous IO within it may well be a perfectly good solution. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As per the question I linked, if you make the deserialization async by putting in a Task.Run, then you can await it and it won't block.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I might be getting all wrong hence my question can you modify my  code so that I see what you mean.

Comment: No, modifying the question wouldn't be the right way of answering it - but you'd just use `await reader.ReadToEndAsync()` instead of `reader.ReadToEnd()`. Note that the parsing/deserialization will still become synchronous. It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve though. "Making it async" isn't a goal in itself - it's a means to an end. What's the "end" here?

Comment: what is the big deal of modifying the code .The means to an end is to read thousand of files in a scalable fashion. I am not going to go into the solution details  as its not relevant ...

Comment: The solution details are important as @DaisyShipton is trying to establish if this is an XY problem or not. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: guys,appreciate your help and the question is getting out of hands.I told what I am trying to achieve."Reading 1000's of files" . I have enough info to carry on if you guys make it as answer I will accept it.thank you

Comment: "what is the big deal of modifying the code" - because at the point at which the question has been modified to make it asynchronous, it's no longer a question about how to make something asynchronous. Are all the JSON files embedded in the assembly? That may well be very important in terms of how well this can be parallelized. Thank you for saying that the point is to allow a large number of files to be read - that's not the only benefit of asynchrony.

Comment: @DaisyShipton some files are embedded and some files are located on disks.

Comment: The question reads: "I have a bunch of json files". It wasn't at all clear that that was thousands. This is why it's important to be as clear as you *possibly* can be when writing a question. Next, it's not clear whether the bottleneck is more likely to be IO or the deserialization itself. That could affect things. Finally, it's not clear whether asynchrony is the way forward here or a simple `Parallel.ForEach`. Accessing a thousand files completely in parallel could easily be slower than handling them in series because the disk isn't a parallel resource.

Comment: All of this is to say: just changing this to `ReadToEndAsync` may not help you much at all, and that's why context is important.

Comment: @DaisyShipton you have a valid point.However you have to appreciate that posting a very lengthy question might put off somebody reading it.So I find that a succint question usually is better in the short term. I cleared in my head that some bits have to be syncronous.  Regarding parallel vs async and when to use one or the other  I am not going to go into this , Its all I/O so async

Comment: "Its all I/O so async" - not it's not. Have you measured how much of the time is IO vs the deserialization itself which is all CPU? Note that you wouldn't have had to make the post "very lengthy" - it doesn't take long to state that you'll be reading thousands of files (a concrete number would be ideal) rather than "a bunch", and that some of them are regular files whereas some are embedded resources. It would also help if you'd say what your performance criteria are, and what your current synchronous code achieves. Imagine how much time would have been saved if you'd included all that.

Comment: @DaisyShipton again I guess I should not have rushed into the question but I think i have established that the deserialization is sync. You comments helped me make it an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the IO *potentially* asynchronous by using `ReadToEndAsync`:

```
public static async Task<T> LoadJsonFile<T>(this Assembly assembly, string fullFilename)
    where T : new()
{
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fullFilename))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are a number of caveats about this:

- The JSON parsing and deserialization is still being performed synchronously. You may find you're CPU-bound rather than IO-bound.
- Not all streams can perform true asynchronous IO. I don't know whether the one returned by `GetManifestResourceStream` can. You may find that it ends up "faking" asynchrony in a way that doesn't help you much.
- If you're trying to load thousands of files, you may well just end up with disk contention anyway. (This will depend on many factors, including what kind of disk it is, how embedded resources handled, and what your mix of files vs resources is.)

I would at least *try* a simple `Parallel.ForEach` loop as well as asynchrony, and see how that compares with the asynchronous code. Make sure you have a good way of testing the performance, and acceptance criteria so you know when you're done.

Comment: .Thank you for your time in answering me question. I will definetely compare parallel vs async as it's not clean cut as you pointed out.